# Animate spritesheet with uequal dimensions in Phaser

Tags: javascript, animation, phaser-framework, sprite-sheet

I have spritesheet:
[image]

As you can see different frames have different sizes here. And I don`t know how to make animation from frames with different sizes. Help me, please.

Comment: Do you have the sprites as one single sprite atlas PNG or lots of separate sprites PNG files?

Comment: @BdR, I have only this .png with green background.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need to create a sprite atlas of those sprites (sometimes also called a sprite texture).

A sprite atlas is a combination of a PNG file and a JSON file (sometimes XML file). The PNG file contains all the sprites neatly packed together and the JSON file contains the coordinates of each sprite in that PNG file. [see more info here](https://www.joshmorony.com/how-to-create-animations-in-phaser-with-a-texture-atlas/).

Phaser (and other libraries) support this format and can load and display these kind of sprites. So what you could do:

1. Cut out each sprite and save as a separate PNG file
2. Give each file a useful name
3. Pack PNG files into a sprite atlas using a utility
4. Load in phaser and animate

With useful names I mean names like `walk_1.png`, `walk_2.png`, `walk_3.png`, `duck_1.png`, `duck_2.png`, `teleport_1.png` etc. something like that.

To pack separate small sprites into one sprite atlas I use [Leshy SpriteSheet Tool](https://www.leshylabs.com/apps/sstool/) which is a freeware tool. There's also [Texture Packer](https://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker) which is a commercial utility with a bit more options, and there are more tools that do the same thing like ShoeBox, [Phaser Editor](http://phasereditor.boniatillo.com) etc.

In Phaser.js you can then load the sprite atlas and add a sprite like so:

```
// either use .atlasJSONArray or .atlasJSONHash, depends on your JSON format
game.load.atlasJSONHash('myspriteatlassheet1', 'img/myspriteatlasfile.png', 'img/myspritefile.json');
var mysprite = game.add.sprite(10, 20, 'myspritesheet1', 'walk_1');
```

And add an animation like so:

```
mysprite.animations.add('jump', ['jump_1', 'jump_2', 'jump_3', 'jump_4'], 20, true); // 20fps, loop=true
mysprite.animations.add('duck', ['duck_1', 'duck_2', 'duck_3'], 30, true);
// etc.

mysprite.animations.play('jump');
```

Comment: What is the easiest way to cut every small frame from .png with opaque background?

Comment: Depends on which you image editor you use. But easiest is probably to select one sprite with a rectangle select, then deselect the surrounding green with Magic Wand select. Hold Alt (Paint Dot Net) or Ctrl (Gimp) to click and subtract the selection. Then copy&paste into a new image and save. And then repeat for all other sprites.